# C linux tcsetpgrp stops parent process even after calling to ignore it

Tags: c, linux, signals

Ok so I wrote this tiny program in order to test how tcsetpgrp behaves and in general handling signals, now I've seen a few posts here asking about tcsetpgrp but for some reason the solutions in those posts are not working for me.

```
int main() {
    signal(SIGINT,sig_handler); 
    static char line[4096];
    int line_num = 0;

    pid_t id = fork();
    if(id == 0 )
    {
        while (fgets(line, 4096, stdin)) {
            printf("\nyou wrote something");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int pgid_child = id;
        printf("child group : %d", pgid_child);
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
        tcsetpgrp(0, pgid_child);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

what I expect to happen:

the terminal will ask for input as long as the user continues to write into it, but if the user presses ctrl+c then the program will end.

what actually happens:

as soon as the child process is set to foreground group the `SIGTTOU` is called to all other processes and the parent process also stops, even though I've asked to ignore that signal.

does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Not related to your issue, but recommend you use `fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)` to derive the size of the array from the array itself, and avoiding duplication of the number.

Comment: Recommend putting a newline at the end of the `"child group"` message so the line gets flushed right away; as shown it's buffered. But I believe that `SIGTTIN` is what's being delivered here.

Comment: `fork` doesn't return a process group ID. The `tcsetpgrp` call is probably returning -1, but your code does not check for errors.

Comment: but the parent process stops because of SIGTTOU why is that?

Comment: @Foghunt What makes you think it's `SIGTTOU` ?

Comment: tbh now that I think about it, I think you're right, how do I approach this problem? I want to set the process group id of the child to be equal that id itself for the sake of simplicity